# Put post parameters into URL

Tags: php, url, cakephp

I use CakePHP 2.5.2. I have standard form, which I send by POST method.

I catch this post in controller and display data from database, but when someone refreshes the page, I can't read data again because parameters were provided by a POST request. So, I want to build URL like this:

```
http://example.com/controller/action/**firstDataFromPost**/**secondDataFromPost**
```

It makes my site refreshable, but I don't know how modify URL.

Comment: You are doing sth wrong there. The pattern you are looking for is called PRG and also requires a get afterwards - and query strings being used. Check out https://github.com/CakeDC/search - where this is implemented correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are really two main options here:

## Use GET

Using the GET HTTP method instead of POST will mean your variables are automatically appended to the end of the querystring:

```
http://example.com/controller/action?firstDataFromPost&secondDataFromPost
```

## Redirect after POST

You can post your form to an action that will assemble the variables required and redirect you to a page that doesn't have a dependent HTTP action anymore. Say you post to `receive()` action:

```
public function receive() {
    $var1 = $this->data['MyForm']['my_field1'];
    $var2 = $this->data['MyForm']['my_field1'];
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'showresults', $var1, $var2));
}
```

Then your `showresults()` action has passed parameters accessible at all times:

```
public function showresults($var1, $var2) {
    // ... display your results here using these variables
}
```

... and your URL would look something like this:

```
http://example.com/controller/showresults/VAR1HERE/VAR2HERE
```

Comment: If what you're implementing is a search (which it sounds like you might), definitely use GET.  POST is for when you're writing data, generally.

Comment: thanks for help you are really fast
Is good, if I will sent utf8 characters like "ó", "ł", "ą", etc. by get method?

Comment: I haven't tried that before, CakePHP might internally convert them to "URL friendly" characters. If not, you might have to pass the strings through `utf8_encode()` or `urlencode()`, and decode after wards